# How to find out the complement of a language of turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, automata

With only using our thinking. What do I have to think about when finding a complement of a Turing machine for example.

L={M∣M is a TM that halts on empty tape after even transition steps}
What's the complement of L would it be:

1. L={M∣M is a TM that does not halt on empty tape after even transition steps}
2. L={M∣M is a TM that halts on empty tape after odd transition steps}

Please give me your train of thought when coming up with a complement for an automaton.

Comment: You're not being asked to find the complement of a *Turing machine*. You're being asked to find the complement of a *language*.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Oh okay, I see where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You cant find the complement of a $TM$ for undecidable languages.
A decidable language is such that a $TM$ which recognizes language membership, always halts with a *yes*. In this case finding the complement of the machine is simple, just reverse the *yes* with the *no*, obtaining the complement of the original decision problem. I leave to you
the task of determining whether the language of your example is decidable or not.

**HINT**: 
you can compare it with the **Halting problem** or $ATM$

Comment: What about a language that was co-recognizable?

Comment: @RickDecker well the complement of co-recognizable is recognizable so yes, you can do it.

Comment: The TM in my question is semi-decidable. When the answer is a YES (that means the machine is in L) the machine will halt but when it's a NO the machine does not halt and therefore we can't find out. However, I'm just confused how to find the complement (U - L) and U(all possible turing machines) is huge. So is compl of L option 1 or 2? or is it both?